# Heroku won't install my dev dependencies with NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false

Tags: node.js, heroku

It refuses to do it although it set

```
NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=false
```

[image: Config variables section of the dashboard]

Do I have to do an extra action in the dashboard?

Answer (score 1):

The NODE_ENV environment variable is set to 'production’ by default. Since you usually don’t want all development dependencies in your production builds, it’s preferable to move only the dependencies you actually need for production builds or change it value to 'development' or any arbitrary string:

```
heroku config:set NODE_ENV=development
```